# Multiple File Conversion with VLC media Player

Tags: conversion, vlc-media-player, video-conversion

I have to convert a number of video files to audio format but its very painful and time consuming to convert them one by one. Is there a way to convert them in a batch with VLC player?

Comment: Do you mean extracting the audio track from each of the video files?

Comment: Yup, its a wmv file and i want to convert it to mp3 or wav format.

Comment: Do you *have* to use VLC for this?

Comment: no there is no restrictions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), you can use the following to extract the audio parts of all WMV files in the current folder to uncompressed WAV (PCM audio):

```
for f in *.wmv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.wmv}.wav"; done
```

Or MP3 – see the [MP3 encoding guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Encoding%20VBR%20%28Variable%20Bit%20Rate%29%20mp3%20audio) for more info:

```
for f in *.wmv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 "${f%.wmv}.mp3"; done
```

These are loops for Linux shells like Bash. For Windows, you'd do something like the following:

```
for %%A IN (*.wmv) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" "%%A.wav"
```

Comment: I also want to increase the playback speed to 1.5x in the converted files.

Comment: You can use the `atempo` filter; see: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

Comment: its first converting to audio and then increasing the playback speed, isn't it?

Comment: It is internally decoding the audio to a raw format, then applying the filter, and then encoding it to either MP3 or PCM audio. You can just insert the filter between `-i "$f"` and `"${f%.wmv}.wav"`.

Comment: thank you very much @slhck you r absolutely a skilled person. :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your OS:

- If you have Windows, it is straightforward to do in the UI:

  - `VLC` -> `Media` -> `Open multiple files`.
- If you are a Mac or a Linux user, there are bash scripts (see
  [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Transcode_multiple_videos/)).
- The above link also has scripts for windows users, if you prefer.

Apart from VLC, HandBrake is a very powerful platform independent (though it was developed for Mac) conversion app that easily allows batch conversion.

Comment: Please include the information from the links in your answer :)

Comment: Updated. I hope that's sufficient